# Odoo8: create quotation from backorders

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

What method is responsible for the creation of quotation? i looked in sale.py but i can't find it. Indeed i want to use that method in backorders process to create a quotation from the backorders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quotation is a sale.order in draft state. The method that creates records for the sale.order model is the `create` method. Indeed this applies to all the models of Odoo/openerp. You can find this method around line 362 in `addons/sale/sale.py`

Answer (score 1):

To create a sale order in draft mode (which is a quotation). You simply need to call the create method for the 'sale.order' model. Something like the following:

```
self.env['sale.order'].create({
                               'state':'draft',
                               'partner_id':
                               ....
})
```

Put all the other values inside the dictionary as per your needs.